# How to get all functions with priority '1' attached to hook 'wp_head'

Tags: hooks

How to get (loop through to disable unnecessary) all functions with priority `'1'` attached to hook `'wp_head'` (`'_wp_render_title_tag'`, `'wp_enqueue_scripts'`, `'noindex'` etc.)?

It is necessary to get it automatically, so that after each new version of WordPress do not keep track of whether the priority `'1'` something else.

Something like:

```
$array_priority_1 = [];

if (doing_action('wp_head')) {
  // Here we get and iterate over all functions related to 'wp_head'
  // and immediately check their priority '1'?
  // suitable and added to the array '$array_priority_1'
  //
  // ...I do not know how to get them and check for priority
}
```

And here we are going through our ready array:

```
foreach ($array_priority_1 as ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The global `$wp_filter` store the hooks and have also his arguments, include the priority. So you can create a small function to debug them. The follow function should helps to list all functions, his arguments if fired on `wp_head`. The foreach loop add the priority of a hook via the run, the doing. So you can list all functions for the hook `wp_head` with priority 10 as example via `var_dump($hooked[0][10]);`.

```
    add_action('all', function($hook) {

        if (doing_action('wp_head')) {

            global $wp_filter;
            if ( ! isset( $wp_filter[ $hook ] ) ) {
                return;
            }

            $hooked = (array) $wp_filter[ $hook ];
            foreach ( $hooked as $priority => $function ) {
                // Prevent buffer overflows of PHP_INT_MAX on array keys.
                // So reset the array keys.
                $hooked   = array_values( $hooked );
                $hooked[] = $function;
            }
            // Print all functions with priority `1`.
            print '<pre>'; print_r($hooked[0][1]); print '</pre>';
        }

        return $hook;
    });
```

### Result

For my test example print all functions with priority `1`

```
Array
(
    [_wp_render_title_tag] => Array
        (
            [function] => _wp_render_title_tag
            [accepted_args] => 1
        )

    [wp_enqueue_scripts] => Array
        (
            [function] => wp_enqueue_scripts
            [accepted_args] => 1
        )

    [noindex] => Array
        (
            [function] => noindex
            [accepted_args] => 1
        )

    [wp_post_preview_js] => Array
        (
            [function] => wp_post_preview_js
            [accepted_args] => 1
        )

)
```

### Additional hint, source

Also this function inside a debug helper plugin should helps you to understand it - https://github.com/bueltge/debug-objects/blob/master/inc/class-page_hooks.php#L90

Comment: You've ignored the priority part of the question, I guess?

Comment: The priority is inside the arguments, in my example inside the var `$hooked`.

Comment: But you don't do anything with it. Your code will print all functions hooked to wp_head, not only these with given priority (as asked in question)... Or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Yes, so I have explained the explanation and the code, include an example to understand easier.

Comment: Then please send the hook as right answer to help others to see, it works.

Comment: @bueltge Sorry. I don't have the reputation to do it...